# Is "meaner, minor things" a sensical phrase?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

I have in my diction this phrase:

> Meaner, minor things

that I've always understood as a way to say "things that are less important than other things."

Before using it in a work email today, I googled the phrase to make sure I was spelling it / understanding it correctly. However, Google yielded no confirmation that this is even a real phrase that people use.

Am I making this phrase up? Does it make sense? Perhaps my spelling is incorrect and google did not throw me a bone? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Understand that "meaner" has several [definitions](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mean).  The most common use is for "unkind", but it can also mean "humble" or "lower class".  I suspect that this latter definition is intended in your quote.

Note that the usage is somewhat archaic, and, while perhaps appropriate in a novel, is probably not ideal for your typical email.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this construction is not used as catch phrase it has a sound basis. From the dictionary definition for "mean", (SOED) "4. Poor in quality or condition; of little value, contemptible; comparatively worthless. *Now chiefly N. Amer. colloq.*", which happens to be proper essentially to AmE, the sense of "meaner, minor things" must be clear immediately clear to the reader.